# Nativescript 8 and angular 12 lazy loading => nsRouterLinkActive not adding active class

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am migrating a project from NS 6.5 with Angular 8.2 to NS 8.1 and Angular 12.2 I have trouble with nsRouterLinkActive directive which doesn't work.
I am using lazy load for my modules like this

`{ path: "mysettings",  loadChildren: () => import("~/app/mysettings/mysettings.module").then((m) => m.MysettingsModule)  }`

and then in my app.component I use the following code to navigate:

`<Label text="&#xf011;" class="fas bottomButton" [nsRouterLink]="['/mysettings']" nsRouterLinkActive="active" pageTransition="slide"></Label>`

Navigation is working fine, my class is working fine, but it never gets added by nsRouterLinkActive directive.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Without trying but looking at the [docs](https://v7.docs.nativescript.org/ng-api-reference/classes/_router_ns_router_link_active_.nsrouterlinkactive.html), shouldn't the `nsRouterLinkActive`  also be wrapped in square brackets, i.e. `[nsRouterLinkActive]`?

Comment: I tried with all the possible ways  but with no luck.
`nsRouterLink="/mysettings" [nsRouterLinkActive]="'active'"`
`nsRouterLink="/mysettings" nsRouterLinkActive="active"`

Comment: @XarisFytrakis have a look at this playground example if you run it and tap the Links you will see the border around the active link

Comment: I don't see the link. But I made a simple playground with angular routing my self and it was working as expected. BUT, when I download the code I realized it was using "@nativescript/core": "6.5.0" with "@angular/core": "8.2.14" so my question is still not answered. Thanks for your time anyway!